# Can I use setTimeout in a return statement

Tags: javascript, react-native, setinterval

How can I `setTimeout`/`setInterval` in a return statement of a functional component.

I have a reusable component which I like to use a `setInterval` to refresh it every set time.

This is the component:

```
    function LikedBTN({ item }) {
    
      const handleLike = (id, action) => {
        var action = "like";
        setLiked(true);
        client
          .post("/pop/like/", { id, action })
          .then((res) => {
            // setLoading(false);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            // setError(err);
            // setLoading(false);
          });
      };
    
      const handleUnlike = (id, action) => {
        var action = "unlike";
        setLiked(false);
        console.log(id, action);
        client
          .post("/pop/like/", { id, action })
          .then((res) => {
            // setLoading(false);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            // setError(err);
            // setLoading(false);
          });
      };
    
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: "row",
            justifyContent: "flex-end",
            textAlignVertical: "center",
            textAlign: "center",
            paddingTop: 8,
          }}
        >
 // setInterval(() => {    --------------------- This is where I will like to use the setInterval
          {item.is_liked && (
            <>
              <AppText style={styles.like}>
                
                {item.likess}
              </AppText>
              <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => handleUnlike(item.id)}>
                <View
                  style={{
                    width: 45,
                    height: 45,
                    marginLeft: -9,
                    marginRight: -10,
                    marginTop: -15,
                  }}
                >
                  <LottieView
                    autoPlay
                    loop={false}
                    source={require("../assets/animations/like-burst.json")}
                  />
                </View>
              </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            </>
          )}
    
          {!item.is_liked && (
            <>
              <AppText style={styles.like}>{item.likess}</AppText>
    
              <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => handleLike(item.id)}>
                <MaterialCommunityIcons
                  style={styles.chipsIcon}
                  name="heart-outline"
                  color={colors.mediumgray}
                  size={21}
                />
              </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            </>
          )}
// }, 1000);  ------------------------ and end it here.
        </View>
      );
    }
    
    export default LikedBTN;
```

Please I will appreciate any help.

Comment: No, you wouldn't be able to use `setInterval` within the return value like that. Instead, look into using `useEffect` with `setInterval`. It's unclear at this point what you expect to be refreshed -- the view should only re-render if it has *new* information that is somehow acquired.

Comment: You should never have to manually rerender a component. Usually that means your usage of react is broken somewhere. What is your motivation for doing this?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what result you're looking to achieve, but you seem to be mixing the two separate concepts of *rendering* and of *maintaining state*.  The component will re-render any time state is updated.  If you have updates to make in intervals or after some time then you'd do that on its own and let the component re-render when it needs to.

Comment: Thank you. Please can you help me. I'm new to react native. I have a like button which when pressed it updates at the backend (add like or remove like), but it doesnt show the count/change the button to the "liked" button as effected on backend until I refresh the page which is not productive.

Comment: @NelsonAdeyinka: Presumably after the AJAX operation successfully returns then you'll just want to update state client-side.  The code shown doesn't appear to maintain any such state.  But ideally whatever information needs to be updated in the UI is maintained in some state in the component (or a parent component somewhere up the hierarchy).  The rendering would show the current state, and the AJAX operation would update the state.  This is pretty fundamental to how React is structured.

Comment: Thank you David. I have been battled this for weeks and I understand what you are saying but I dont know how to go about it and yes, this code above is a reusable component which I pass the item to be liked to the component, the parent component maintain the state. Can I share the parent component if you can help please

Comment: @NelsonAdeyinka: It looks like the state to be updated is `item.is_liked`.  Which looks like it's in a parent component.  So this component might expose a prop called `onLike` which is a function to call when the AJAX operation completes successfully.  The parent component would pass this component a function which updates `item.is_liked` for the given `item`.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean, are you saying I should create a state `onLike` pass that as a prop to the parent component and used that in a parent component (if yes, How?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React isn't structured like this at all.  You don't want to manually re-render the component (and the way you're attempting to do so is simply a syntax error).  You want to *update state*.

Currently the state you want to change appears to be:

```
item.is_liked
```

Which is passed to the component as a prop:

```
function LikedBTN({ item }) {
```

So presumably your component is used somewhere like this:

```
<LikedBTN item={someItem} />
```

Since the "item" is maintained in a parent component, it would need to be updated in that parent component.  One way to do this is to pass a callback function as another prop.  So you'd expose a prop like this:

```
function LikedBTN({ item, onLike }) {
```

And call that function when the AJAX operation successfully completes:

```
client
  .post("/pop/like/", { id, action })
  .then((res) => {
    onLike && onLike();
  })
```

Then the parent component would provide a function that updates *its* state.  For example:

```
<LikedBTN
  item={someItem}
  onLike={() => {
    // update the state of "someItem" here
  }}
/>
```

So it's up to the component which maintains the state of the "items" to update that state.  And it's up to `LikedBTN` to provide a callback that gets invoked when that state needs to be updated.